# How to link my styles to through a one root path created on php?

Tags: php, root

If I am using this:

```
$subDir = '/myfolder site on wamp/';
$includePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $subDir;
```

Then how do I link my styles to that root directory?

I've been trying this : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$includePath.'/css/main.css">`

But it is not working.

Comment: Show a bit more context on how you wrote out that string concatenation snippet. Also reveal the final HTML output of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use relative path like, if you have following directory structure-

```
myfolder
|-->css
    |-->main.css
|-->index.php
```

The relative path should be like -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
```

But if you want to have an absolute path than try to check with following code that what value is suitable for your web application-

```
<?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>
```

Or create a method which returns the absolute path like-

```
<?php
function getAddress() {
    $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';
    $fileptrn = '/'.basename(__FILE__).'/';
    return $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].preg_replace($fileptrn,"",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 } 
?>
```

Then call it like-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo getAddress().'css/main.css'; ?>">
```

Comment: the problem is that i have:my diffrent pages into diffrent folder lets say services.php in a folder called services but im using one sma include to include the styles so I have <?php include('include/head.php'); ?> in all the pages So the path to my styles depend or where i am so I need to link them pointing to the root

Comment: @alexisdwd check the $_SERVER content using print_r() method, it will list all the values, and you will get idea that which one is suitable.